# Updating wpf UI from another thread asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a WPF UI and I want to update it asynchronously from another thread by calling some events.

I know how to call events and invoke them in UI Thread, but I want to do it async.

```
public partial class HomeUI 
{
    public HomeUI()
    {
        var test = new LogicClass();
        test.UI_StartPlaying += StartPlaying;

        new Thread(test.Start).Start();
    }

    private void StartPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var streamAddress = (e as UIUpdateEventArgs).StreamAddress;
            vlc.Stop();
            vlc.Media = new LocationMedia(streamAddress);
            vlc.Play();
        }));
    }

}


public class LogicClass
{
    public event EventHandler UI_StartPlaying;
    public void Start()
    {
        DoSomethings();
        UI_StartPlaying(this, new UIUpdateEventArgs(streamAddress));
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

class UIUpdateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    string StreamAddress {get; set;}
    public UIUpdateEventArgs( string streamAddress)
    {
        this.StreamNumber = streamNumber;
    }
}
```

but in this code, when something happening in `DoSomethingElse()` part that cause delay or stop the logic thread, UI freezes.
***Edit:*** in `DoSomethingElse()` part, I run 2 Threads that one of them do all the DB transactions and have some delay. this delay, make the vlc pause (freeze on a random frame) on the UI and then make the whole UI freeze.
Obviously, when I comment these transactions, program work properly.
What should I do to make the `UIEventUpdate` run asynchronously with my `Logic Thread`?

Comment: _when something happening in DoSomethingElse() part that cause delay or stop the logic thread_ It shouldn't, as DoSomethingElse runs on a Thread. The 'something' needs explaining.

Comment: We'd need to see how you run the Db transactions.

Comment: I know that all the DB transactions could be better written, but I want to prevent UI freezing for that or any other reasons. How can I play a stream on UI, without any dependency with other part of the program.

Comment: Your DB actions shouldn't block the GUI so it's in the code around them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to get what you need. This function is returning directly, the delegate gets scheduled and called later.

If your requirement is that `DoSomethingElse()` is called after `StartPlaying` finished, you have to `await` the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` call.

I don´t know about `LocationMedia` but if `new LocationMedia(streamAddress);` is an expensive creation (takes long and/or needs lot of memory) i would do it outside the `Dispatcher` delegate if possible.

```
var streamAddress = (e as UIUpdateEventArgs).StreamAddress;
var media = new LocationMedia(streamAddress);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    vlc.Stop();
    vlc.Media = media;
    vlc.Play();
}));
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Use Dispatcher.InvokeAsync Method instead of Invoke method.
[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync(v=vs.110).aspx)